# How do I override box-align css property for specific child?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox element with three children:

```
<div class="box">
    <div>un</div>
    <div>deux</div>
    <div>trois</div>
</div>
```

I want to align the first two children to the top of the box, but for the third child, I want to vertically center it. I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I tried:

```
.box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 95px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  font: 14px Arial;

  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
}

.box > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;

}

.box > div:nth-child(1){ background : #FCC; height: 20px;}
.box > div:nth-child(2){ background : #CFC; height: 25px;}
.box > div:nth-child(3){ background : #CCF; height: 15px; -webkit-box-align: center;}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TDUd5/15/

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you mean place the text, "trois" in the center of the box?

Comment: I would like the div containing trois to be in the center.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it's possible to change one flex item's alignment, since that is being set by the parent, so an alternative is a mini-wrapper for each column which would set the align from there: http://jsfiddle.net/TDUd5/30/

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="start"><div>un</div></div>
  <div class="start"><div>deux</div></div>
  <div class="center"><div>trois</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 95px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  font: 14px Arial;

  display: -webkit-box;
}

.box > div.start { -webkit-box-align: start; }
.box > div.center { -webkit-box-align: center; }

.box div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
}

/* our colors */ 
.box > div:nth-child(1) > div{ background : #FCC; height: 20px;}
.box > div:nth-child(2) > div{ background : #CFC; height: 25px;}
.box > div:nth-child(3) > div{ background : #CCF; height: 15px;}
```